# scaling a single image for tablets android

Tags: image, scaling, device

My project has a requirement to display image in rightpane of tablet in both portrait and landscape mode. Images are stored in sdcard. Also splashscreen is to shown in both phones and tablets. Currently it has 6 splashscreens both mode supporting mdpi, hdpi, & xhdpi. same incase of tablets. 6 for rightpane images total 18 images. It makes the content too heavy. creating bitmap from sdcard sometimes throws exception out of memory creatbitmap, createdrawable methods. Can't we scale a single high resolution image for all sizes. A single high resolution splashscreen image for portrait, 1 for landscape, 1+1 for tablet and 1+1 for rightpane without loosing quality. Please help. Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole idea of having different resolution images is to make the app run smoothly on all devices. If you manually start scaling on each event, which is an expensive process by the way, it might irritate the user as it might take time on some devices.

Anyways, you can still scale it if you want without getting OutOfMemoryError by downsampling the image.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; // Better to keep it in power of 2 (as told in docs)
Bitmap bitmapScaled = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

To change resolution

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, width, height, isFilterNeeded);
```

Although I would strongly recommend you to read [How to Resize And Rotate Image](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html)
and also [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: thanks bharath for your quick response. I'll definitely try this solution and will let u know. Thanks again.